# Capture KeyCode on keypress in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keypress, keycode, arrow-keys

I am currently trying to capture the key-code in a keypress event in JavaScript for a text box.  I'm using the following line to detect the keycode:

```
var iKey = e.keyCode || e.charCode || e.which || 0;
```

However, the arrow keys are coming up as ', % and so forth.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be doing this:

```
var iKey = e.keycode || e.which || 0;
```

[Quirksmode explains your problem well](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html):

> The two properties are keyCode and charCode. Put (too) simply, keyCode
>   says something about the actual keyboard key the user pressed, while
>   charCode gives the ASCII value of the resulting character. These bits
>   of information need not be the same; for instance, a lower case 'a'
>   and an upper case 'A' have the same keyCode, because the user presses
>   the same key, but a different charCode because the resulting character
>   is different.